# Having issue with fixed length data while displaying into front end

Tags: wicket-6

I am using MultiLineLabel component  to display fixed length data in to front end,
But it has issue while displaying the data 
when data line contains multiple spaces in between e.g.

```
1234232     44343 4343343
11111111111144343 4343343
```

Here the first line getting truncated

```
1234232 44343 4343343
11111111111144343 4343343
```

as i saw this component its using `<p></p>`
to display data and `<P>` has property it will truncate the spaces on display.

Can somebody assist me how can  display my fixed length data on front end ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with the `<p>`. This is a common property of HTML - multiple spaces are collapsed into one.

You can pre-process the String you pass to MultiLineLabel with: Strings.replace(original, " ", "&nbsp;");